# greensock timline does not work properly

Tags: gsap

My greensock timeline only executes the second timeline instruction. If I comment out the second one, the first tween works. What is wrong with the timing?

```
        tl.to($img, .3, {rotation: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}, 0)
      .fromTo($img, .3, {rotation: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}, {rotation: 10, yoyo:true, repeat:-1, ease:Linear.easeNone}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last parameter on each of the timeline calls is called the position parameter. by setting that parameter to 0 on both method calls you are telling both animations tu run at the 0 seconds mark of the timeline. this effectively being the beginning. So you are telling both animations to execute at the same time so that is why you see only the second animation and when you delete that call you see the first. 
So, if you want one animation to run immediately after another you should remove the position parameter altogether from the second fromTo call.

you can also define an offset meaning you can set the second animation to run slightly before the first ends or slightly after. you would do this by setting the position parameter to '-=0,5' which would start the second animation 0.5 before the first animation finishes or '+=0.5' which would start the animation .5 seconds after.